# Regular expression to find a value and return it in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string

I've been trying to figure this out for 2 hours now with no success. Its a bit complicated for me i guess.
I am trying to parse a script file in PHP and return some values to the user. The ones i want are like this:

_**value** = object **runFunction** blah blah blah

Basically what i want is (in an algorithm):

- **IF** case-insensitive runFunction is found in the line (because it might be runfunction)
- **AND** the line starts with _ (underscore) (or if possible before the = there is a value that starts with _   to be sure of the result)
- **THEN** return that underscore value before the = to me.

Usually 99.9% the format is like this...But there are small cases it can be like this:

_**value** = **_object runFunction** blah blah blah
(in case the _ after the = messes things up).

Any help here :) ?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Show your code

Comment: This is what i got so far:  '/\_::([A-Za-z\/]+)\runfunction/'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like:

```
$str = 'YOUR FILE CONTENTS HERE';
$match = preg_match_all('/(_[a-zA-Z0-9_]+) ?= ?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+ runFunction/s',$str,$matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

you'll probably need to add the multiline flag.

Comment: Its 99.9999% what i want :) But totally forgot that there is a chance _value can be s_value as well sometimes....its it possible to ignore results that have anything else before the _ ??
If not its ok, i'll substr it.
But wow that was fast :)

Comment: also isnt it for case insensitive :
$match = preg_match_all('/(_[a-zA-Z0-9_]+) ?= ?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+ (?i)runfunction/s',$holdcontents,$matches);

??

Comment: Ian how would i ignore results that HAVE anything before the _    ? I totally forgot about those...some cases might have s_value

Comment: if _value can be s_value then the (_[a-zA-Z0-9_]+) would become (s?_[a-zA-Z0-9_]+) that would make the s optional anything else would require a lookbehind check to actually ignore. ((?<[s\n])_[a-zA-Z0-9_]+) this SHOULD match only (s OR newline)_varname not tested but have a play

Comment: s in s_value could be any small letter. Right now this: /(\s_[a-zA-Z0-9_]+) ?= ?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+ runfunction/i works 100% but i dont get all the results of the page...it stops at the first one. Just need to parse the whole thing and it will work :) 
Thanks

Comment: add m to the flags at the end (/sm) that wil make it multiline. if s is any lowercase character then ((?<[a-z])?_[a-zA-Z0-9_]+) so your full regex shoudl now be something like: '/((?<[a-z])?_[a-zA-Z0-9_]+) ?= ?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+ runFunction/sm'

Comment: That brings errors: Compilation failed: unrecognized character after (?< at offset 4

But since i can do preg_match_all and get all the result, why go multiline ?   \s_ works

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
if (preg_match('/^_([^=]+?)(?=\s*=).*runfunction/im', $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[1];
} else {
    $result = "";
}
```

You can exclude the initial "start" anchor is your underscore might not be at the beginning of the line

Here is the regex by itself.  The results are in capturing group 1

```
^_([^=]+?)(?=\s*=).*runfunction
```

The regex 
   look for beginning of line
   match the first underscore
   capture everything that is not an '=' into capturing group 1
     provided it is followed by 0 or more spaces and an equal sign.
   then capture everything up to a runfunction.

Case insensitive and multiline options need to be set

If the first underscore does not need to be at the beginning of the line, eliminate the anchor.

Comment: It seems to work here in RegexBuddy.  Perhaps my code is wrong.  I have simplified the regex -- no need for lookarounds since I am using a numbered capturing group.  I have also posted the regex separately.

Comment: yeah i see that it works in regexbuddy, but for some reason in php it doesnt 

$match = preg_match_all('/^_([^=]+?)(?=\s*=).*runfunction/im',$holdcontents,$matches);

Comment: Ian's works perfectly besides the fact that return values that do start with a letter.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with match vs match_all and the capturing group.  But I don't know enough about php to help further.  So long as you have a solution...

Comment: Well yours is 100% accurate but doesnt work in php, Ian's works with php but totally forgot about the extra letter in the front and brings kinda wrong results lol. I'll wait a bit, maybe he'll answer

Comment: 5.2.6 is the version...forgot to mention it sorry

Comment: uhhhh i think i know what the problem is.....This is a script file...so its not always starting at the beginning of the line...could be inside a function so there is spacing (from the left of _)

Comment: did you remove the start of string anchor as I suggested?

Comment: \s_([^=]+?)(?=\s*=).*runfunction  .Like this only it brings good results, but its case insensitive and setting it to /i  one of the values gets returned with a bit from the line above (cause it has a value _x in it)

Comment: So far this brings 100% correct results: (\s_[a-zA-Z0-9_]+) ?= ?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+ runfunction/i    ....But it doesnt work in php lol

Comment: sorry, but Ian's work perfect with the extra spacing addition. Thank you so much for your time and effort though.